# How to export million rows from DB to CSV via ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, csv

I have million rows in my DB. I need to export all them into csv file.
The problem is that i have timeout limit error.

So. I decided to do it via ajax.

I created ajax that generates me few tmp csv files

```
function chunkedExport()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "transactions/",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: $("#transactions").serialize(),
        async: false,
        success: function(response)
        {
            if (response.status === "continue")
            {
                $("#start_from").val(response.start_from);
                $("#client_file_name").val(response.client_file_name);
                $("#file_name").val(response.tmp_file_name);
                $("#step").val(response.step);
                chunkedExport();
            } else {
                console.log('DOWNLOAD');
                $("#start_from").val(0);
                $("#client_file_name").val('');
                $("#file_name").val('');
                $("#step").val(1);
                $("#export_type").val("");
                $('#csv_format').val("");

                document.location.href = '/transactions_export_csv/'+response.client_file_name+'/'+response.tmp_file_name+'/'+response.total_iterations+'/'
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log([xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError]);
            $("#start_from").val(0);
            $("#client_file_name").val('');
            $("#file_name").val('');
            $("#step").val(1);
            $("#export_type").val("");
            $('#csv_format').val("");
        }
    });
}
```

the question is how to combine them all into one csv file and download it?

Comment: just "using ajax" does not solve _any_ of your problems. personally, i'd suggest preparing by writing the CSV-file server side and then downloading the generated file when it's done. the first is a background job that can run without time limit, the second is a simple static download.

Comment: I would suggest you to do this by using cronjobs. Create a request in database when user click on download button. Run Cron every minute that will read active request and create CSV file on server then send csv link to user.

Comment: `The problem is that i have timeout limit error.` - run via the command line, use UnBuffered queries if your using PDO, don't try to output too much.  I've done upwards of 150 million rows this way, (I have very powerful server though 64Gb ram)